# Correctly style Image inside grid-auto-rows

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm working on a website splash page which should show rows of same height. Each row has a title and further text items and one image.
The text and image items should align at the bottom of each row as shown on following screenshot

[image]

On Hover, the image should slide up to max height which fits into the row.

**My question is:**
Can I access the current value of 1fr from parent row `grid-auto-rows: 1fr;`to give the image on hover a max height?

This is how my code currently looks like:

```css
html, body {margin:0; padding:0}

.jumbo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: yellow;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
}

.jumbo__item {
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  font-size: 20vh;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
  #overflow: hidden;
}

.jumbo__rowtags{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.jumbo__tag {
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.jumbo__tag-high{
  height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.jumbo__tag-high:hover{
  height: auto;
  max-height: 200px;
}

.a {background: lightblue; }
.b {background: lightgreen}
.c {background: lightgrey}
```

```html
<div class="jumbo">
  <div class="jumbo__item a">
    Dogs
  </div>
  <div class="jumbo__item b">
    and
    <section class="jumbo__rowtags">
      <span class="jumbo__tag jumbo__tag-high"><img src="https://placeimg.com/350/200/nature"></span>
      <span class="jumbo__tag">Hello</span>
      <span class="jumbo__tag">World</span>
    </section>
  </div>
  <div class="jumbo__item c">
    cats
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the image and its container to be `height:100%` of the row then consider a transform animation

```css
html, body {margin:0; padding:0}

.jumbo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: yellow;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
}

.jumbo__item {
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  font-size: 20vh;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
  #overflow: hidden;
}

.jumbo__rowtags{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  top:0; /* added */
  
}

.jumbo__tag {
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.jumbo__tag-high{
  height: 100%; /* added */
  overflow: hidden;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.jumbo__tag-high img {
   height:100%; /* added */
   transform:translateY(calc(100% - 30px));
   transition:1s all;
}

.jumbo__tag-high:hover img{
   transform:translateY(0%);
}

.a {background: lightblue; }
.b {background: lightgreen}
.c {background: lightgrey}
```

```html
<div class="jumbo">
   <div class="jumbo__item a">
     Dogs
   </div>
   <div class="jumbo__item b">
     and
     <section class="jumbo__rowtags">
       <span class="jumbo__tag jumbo__tag-high"><img src="https://placeimg.com/350/200/nature"></span>
       <span class="jumbo__tag">Hello</span>
       <span class="jumbo__tag">World</span>
     </section>
   </div>
   <div class="jumbo__item c">
     cats
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Nice!  Just one more little question. In case an Item does not have an image the "tags" are not positioned on bottom anymore: https://codepen.io/t-book/pen/YzXBeMz?editors=1100 is there an easy fix for it?

Comment: @tBook add a hidden element using pseudo element that will replace the image; https://jsfiddle.net/8z3bekrd/